# как включить режим защиты батареи через adb?

Tags: android, adb

на lenovo android 10 есть функция режима защиты батареи. Мне нужно включить ее через adb. adb shell settings put global battery_charging_limit не предлагать. Пошарил в инете что то ничего про нее нету
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему не предлагать?

Comment: Не то что нужно